# This bash command runs on OSX but not on Busybox ..why?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-arguments, busybox, qnap

I've got this bash one-liner , it runs fine on OSX, but doesn't on Linux, I'm suspecting the linux distro (Busybox) on my Qnap has got something to do with this .

Here is the command that runs on OSX :

```
find . -type f -name "*.mp4" -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -c:v copy -c:a libfaac -af "volume=23dB" "fix/$0"' '{}' \;
```

Now on the Qnap:

```
find . -type f -name "*.mp4" -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -c:v copy -c:a libfaac -af "volume=23dB" "fix/$0"' '{}' \;
```

returns :

> BusyBox v1.01 (2015.05.21-17:32+0000) multi-call binary
>
> Usage: find [PATH...] [EXPRESSION]
>
> Search for files in a directory hierarchy.  The default PATH is the
>   current directory; default EXPRESSION is '-print'
>
> EXPRESSION may consist of:    -follow     Dereference symbolic links.
>     -name PATTERN   File name (leading directories removed) matches
>   PATTERN.  -print      Print (default and assumed).
>
> -type X     Filetype matches X (where X is one of: f,d,l,b,c,...)   -perm
>   PERMS Permissions match any of (+NNN); all of (-NNN);             or exactly
>   (NNN)     -mtime TIME Modified time is greater than (+N); less than (-N);
>             or exactly (N) days

Like if the find command wasn't working, so if I execute the **find** command alone :

```
find . -type f -name "*.mp4"
```

it works just fine, I get all my files, so I suspect the problem is passing the files to the **exec** command, and that's where I can't figure it out

---

*bash version osx* : GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)

*bash version linux* : GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Why don't you just pipe? In this particular case it's easier to debug if you pipe.

Comment: BusyBox isn't your typical Linux system (i.e., mostly POSIX with some extensions).  Rather, BusyBox is a collection of utilities which lack many features.  On the positive side, a script that you can run on BusyBox is likely to run on other systems.  The question should be retitled to say "BusyBox".

Comment: Good idea, how would I pipe each file to ffmpeg ?

Comment: @ThomasDickey yeah, that's what I suspect, don't know how to get around it to get my one liner to work on Busybox ..

Comment: I wouldn't try it as a one-liner: making the complicated argument of `-exec` into a separate script would probably be a good starting point.  By keeping the pieces simple, you can pinpoint the limitations to work around one-by-one.

Comment: @ThomasDickey, okay, not pipe, but the simpliest loop would do it. `for i in $(find . -type f -name "*.mp4"); do ffmpeg "..."; done`. Or pipe to `awk` and then to shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *suspect* it's based on the single/double quote positioning tripping up find.

Typically I always use something like this in a script file (say conv.sh) for more complex operations:

```
find . -type f -name "*.mp4" | while read FILE
do
  ffmpeg -i "$FILE" -c:v copy -c:a libfaac -af "volume=23dB" "fix/$FILE"
done
```

Now run this file with debugging:

```
bash -xv ./conv.sh
```

A quick and dirty script that should work.